# Regex - Replace input and output as decimals only?

Tags: regex

If I have an input such as any one of the following, or even something else...(these are longitude and latitude)

`123.4567 N` and `123.456789 W`

`123.45678` and `-123.456789`

or something like

`1sd48.123457` and `-1s44.456789`

How would I use regex to only get the number and decimal out of it?

One express that I use is `[A-Za-z]", ""` which remove all the letters. What if the input contains other weird characters? I only want the number and decimal to be left behind once regex is done.

Comment: Extract with `-?\d+\.\d+`

Comment: For something such as `-123.456789` , the `-` is still in the result

Comment: Then do not use `-?`, use plain `\d+\.\d+`.

Comment: My post seems to be a duplicate, but I did not find that post. Maybe I should have searched for latitude longitude instead. Thank you for correcting my post and for answering! Please post as an answer if you want me to mark it as resolve